# I want to delete specific dates from a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has a column containing dates and cities, these dates are repeated every time a new city appears.

I want to leave only 4 specific dates and delete the others. I discovered a function that does this, but that runs one date at a time.

I want to create a function that does this whole process and leaves only the dates I want. Follow the df and code that eliminates one date at a time.

[image]

> `df[df.column != '2020-06-19']`

Comment: can you please post the data in clear text and also can you please provide your desired output as an option so we know what you are looking for. I dont understand when you say `leave only the dates`. Are you looking for unique dates in the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
df = df[df.column.isin(['2020-06-19', '2020-06-20', '2020-06-21'])]
```

or if you want to remove these dates.

```
df = df[~df.column.isin(['2020-06-19', '2020-06-20', '2020-06-21'])]
```